# String equal in Java

Tags: java, string

I have to write a hangman homework assignment. We aren't allowed to use any char array and only use String methods to manipulate the string itself. A problem I'm running into is when I try to check the string builder for duplicates.

This is my hangman method

```
public void playHangMan(Scanner guessWord)
{
    int error = 6;
    String letter;
    boolean vali, dup;

    displayHangman();// call displayHangman method

    // get input, lower case input, and then validate in a loop
    do
    {
        letter = guessWord.nextLine();
        letter = lowerGuess(letter); // call lowerGuess method
        vali = letter.matches("[a-z]");

        dup = checkDup(letter); // call checkDup method

        if(vali == false)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter only a SINGLE letter: ");
        }
        else if(dup == true)
        {
            System.out.print("Duplicated letter, please enter another: ");
        }

        if(dup == false && vali == true)
        {
            this.guessAns.append(letter);
        }

    }
    while(vali == false && dup == false);


}// end playHangman method
```

My duplicate method:

```
private boolean checkDup(String letter)
{
    int i;
    boolean dup = false;

    // check guessAns StringBuilder for duplicate letters
    for(i = 0; i <= this.guessAns.length() - 1 && dup == false; i++)
    {
        if(letter.equals(this.guessAns.charAt(i)))
        {
            dup = true;
        }
    }

    if(dup == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}// end checkDup method
```

The problem is that my checkDup method isn't finding any duplicates. I tried appending the letter a into my string builder and entering in the value a for letter, but still no luck. Can it be that `letter.equals(this.guessAns.charAt(i))` is comparing a String to a Char and that's why my checkDup method is failing to find duplicates? Can someone explain a way that I can get around this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use a [`Set<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or [`String.indexOf(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Note that the bottom half of `checkDup` can be simplified to `return dup;`.

Comment: @PaulBellora .. which can itself be simplified by removing the `dup` variable.

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks! You're right. Will definitely change that up.

Comment: @user2864740 has a point - you could replace `dup = true;` with `return true;` and put `return false;` at the end. +1 for a well-written question btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 ways you could work around this:

```
letter.charAt(0) == guessAns.charAt(i);
```

The solution above is under the assumption that `letter` is a single `char`.

The other way is to invoke `Character.toString` on the `char`:

```
letter.equals(Character.toString(guessAns.charAt(i)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your input really helped out.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `String.equals(char)` will always return false, as Strings never compare as equal to Characters. Do this to compare them as characters:

```
if(letter.charAt(0) == this.guessAns.charAt(i)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of checking for duplicates: using a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html). The regex `.*([a-z])\1.*` will match any `String` with a repeated character between `a` and `z`. To go more general, `.*(.)\1.*` will match any `String` with any repeated character.

```
dup = letter.matches(".*([a-z])\\1.*");
```

How this works: `.` matches any character and`*` means 0 or more times, so `.*` means any amount of any character (it "consumes" any amount of characters). `(` starts a [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html); `)` ends a group. `[a-z]` matches any character between `a` to `z`. `\1` is a [backreference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). Therefore, the regex looks for any character `[a-z]` which is immediately followed by the same character.

Note: If you are looking to see if the `String` contains the same character even when separated, then this should work: `.*([a-z]).*\1.*`